# Why decimal.Decimal(0)**decimal.Decimal(0) doesn't return 1

Tags: python, math

Why does `decimal.Decimal(0)**decimal.Decimal(0)` not return 1 but an error?

```
import decimal
decimal.Decimal(0)**5  # works and returns Decimal('0') as it should
decimal.Decimal(0)**0  # doesn't not work and should return 1
decimal.Decimal(0)**decimal.Decimal(0)  # same
0**0  # works and returns 1
```

I could use `if` statements to bypass the error I get (`decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]`) but it looks quite dirty to do so.

EDIT : I've always learned in school that 0^0 was 1 but (cf. comments) it is not. So if I want it to be 1 I guess I'll do it manually (in my case that's the desired behaviour), I wasn't aware there was debate as to its value.

Comment: [0⁰ is undefined.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0**0)

Comment: 0 to the power of 0 equaling 0 is a convention that makes the most sense in discrete contexts. It's not as useful for real numbers.

Comment: Related discussion from Math.SE: [Zero to the zero power – is 0^0=1
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11150/646141). Quoting the top answer, _"In general, there is no good answer as to what 0^0 "should" be, so it is usually left undefined."_ See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: I've always learned in school that 0^0 was 1. So if I want it to be 1 I guess I'll do it manually (in my case that's the desired behaviour), I wasn't aware there was debate as to its value.

Comment: (Whoops, should've written "0 to the power of 0 equaling 1" earlier. Too late to edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `decimal` module follows the [IBM General Decimal Arithmetic Specification](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decarith.html), which [says](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/daops.html#refpower) that 0 to the power of 0 raises an Invalid Operation condition and produces NaN. By default, Python raises a `decimal.InvalidOperation` exception for Invalid Operation conditions, but you can change the context settings to get the NaN if you want:

```
In [1]: import decimal

In [2]: decimal.getcontext().traps[decimal.InvalidOperation] = False

In [3]: decimal.Decimal(0)**decimal.Decimal(0)
Out[3]: Decimal('NaN')
```

As for why the spec defines the operation this way, 0^0=1 is a convention that makes the most sense in discrete contexts. It's not as useful for real numbers. IEEE 754 picked 1.0 for the return value, but IBM made a different choice. Both choices are reasonable.

Comment: "you can change the context settings to get the NaN if you want", can you change it to 1?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows: Nope.

Comment: The part that never made any sense to me is that the standard _also_ specifies that `decimal.Decimal("inf")**decimal.Decimal("0")` should give `1`.